# getting a list of all lowercase words in a file

Tags: text-processing, grep, pipe, sort, tr

I'm trying to get a list of all lowercase words in a file. This far I've gotten to the point of getting a list with the command line

```
cat filename.txt | tr ' ' \\n | grep -w '[[:lower:]]*' | sort -u | less
```

However, this command doesn't get rid of the non-alphabetic characters in the list; I get a list with the form

```
(which
(which,
about
about,
about.
about:
about;
about?
which
```

I'm interested only in the lines with only the words. How can I get them with a similar line command?

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C grep -w '[[:lower:]]*'`

Comment: `cat file |egrep -o '[a-z][a-z]* '` does this work?

Comment: @Bibek_G the same as the comment to Serge's solution: I also get partial matches dropping the initial Uppercase letter...

Comment: I figured out that I can achieve the desired result by `grep -wo '[[:lower:]]*'`; so I only had to add the `-o` switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' <file | grep -xE '[[:lower:]]+'
```

Comment: I see: the key was to add the delimiters `^` and `$` to my grep regexp; correct?

Comment: That regex also match blank lines, but in this case it worked, because there'is no blank lines in `grep` input, thanks to `tr`.

Comment: ... but I achieved a similar effect with my `tr`, correct?

Comment: tr first truncated any multiple spaces in your file and provides a newline feed `\n` each time it finds a space. The output then goes into egrep which searches for only lowercase  chars from start of line `^` to end of line `$`  and outputs  the match.

Comment: If i'm little off on `tr` part, correct me. I just learnt about it from manual after your post.

Comment: @TarsTarkas: Not the same, yours only convert space, while `[:blank:]` contains tab `\t`. The `[\n*]` is required by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
sed 's/[^A-Za-z]\+/\n/g;s/$/\n/;s/[^\n]*[A-Z][^\n]*\n//g;s/\n$//' <input_file | sort -u
```

Comment: I get also words beginning with Uppercase, but truncated to the lowercase part...

Comment: You did not define a `word` )). Ok I will fix it for you

Comment: See the  update.

Comment: We’re looking for substantial answers that provide some explanation and context.  Please don’t give just a one-line answer; explain how it works.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @G-Man Why you did not leave the same comment at the accepted answer? Let me guess... because cuonglm has 56k points?

Comment: imho no explanation is needed: it is enough to read the regex. (I'm not that fluent to speak regex, but I can read it :o)

Answer (score 1):

After a little while I came back to this question, and just want to show my fixed command which did the trick, for the record.

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' < filename.txt | grep -wo '[[:lower:]]*' | sort -u | less -N
```

Comment: If you're going to use `grep -wo` (a GNUism), you don't need the `tr`. That also changes the definition  of *word* to be sequences of alnum characters or underscore as opposed to blank separated words. For instance in `Foo-bar's toe`, that prints `bar`, `s` and `toe` as opposed to just `toe`.